# Firefox propagates context menu event directly past DOM root on disabled input

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom-events

I'm trying to disable context menus.  To do this I `stopPropagation` and `preventDefault` on `body`.  This works fine, except with disabled `input` elements in Firefox.

Enabled `input` elements properly bubble the event to body, but disabled ones allow the right click menu to appear.  I'm sure the event is being sent directly to something higher up the DOM but I've tried attaching the listener to both `document` and `window` with no luck.

```js
document.body.addEventListener("contextmenu", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log("context menu blocked at body");
});

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("input"))
    .forEach(input => {
        input.addEventListener("contextmenu", e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            console.log("context menu blocked at input");
        });
    });
```

```css
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="I am disabled" disabled />
<input type="text" value="I am not disabled" />
```

I've also tried adding blocking event listeners to the inputs on the page.  The enabled one works as expected; the disabled one has no change in behavior.

This behavior does not appear to be present in Chromium/Webkit browsers (Chrome, Safari, Brave).

**Is there any way to block context menus in Firefox on disabled input elements?**  Is there higher level DOM element I could attach my blocking listener to to catch all fall-through events?

Comment: @dandavis I'm sorry - I don't think I understand your question.

Comment: @dandavis yeah, I tried that too.  If you take a look at the code above I add a listener to all inputs on the page but disabled elements don't raise mouse events.

Comment: oops, sorry about that... If that doesn't work, I don't think anything will. What's the harm of allowing it on a disabled input anyway, they can't paste or anything, right?

Comment: Have you try to prevent on right button click event?

Comment: @dandavis the goal is to replace context menus across the app with custom ones.  If an input is disabled, that event should bubble to the inputs parent and use its custom menu.

Comment: perhaps this can be done in css: `input:disabled{ pointer-events: none; }` should prevent any kind of mouse interaction.

Comment: @pioro90 Do you mean using `e.which` on a click event?  Click events also are not fired on either body or the element when the input is disabled :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you cannot disable context menus on disabled inputs in Firefox, you can do something 99% the same using CSS to prevent mouse interaction completely:

`input:disabled{ pointer-events: none; }`